Git strategy for automating releases with automated commits to repo?
I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but I don't know where else to post it.
I want to automate my release process with Gitlab CI. The flow would look like this:

Developer creates /release commit
Changelog is generated and committed to repository (either a custom script or Gitlab's Changelog feature)
Get hashes of files in repo with ansible-sign and commit the list of hashes to the repo
Create tag (this can either be committed to the repo prior to release, or will be created automatically with the release if tag doesn't exist)
Create release on the tag revision

This process of course consists of several commits, each of which launches a new CI pipeline (unless jobs are skipped with various rules).
I initially had all steps running on a single commit, using git commit --amend to update the commit with the new changes, but others have recommended against this as it's apparently bad practice.
Without amend, I would effectively need any step that commits to the repository to then launch a new pipeline to run the next step. This seems like it could quickly become overly complicated with all kinds of custom rules to conditionally run certain jobs at certain triggers, etc.
Looking for any guidance on how I should approach this--do I use amend to keep it all on the same commit/same pipeline, but then possibly introduce difficulties for the developers by rewriting git history? Or do I try to daisy-chain commits/pipelines together?
Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Aim for a single pipeline. Don't rewrite the history of a shared branch.

Can you clarify what #1 means? What changes are in this commit? And, maybe this is a GitLab specific concept, but what does /release mean in the context of the new commit? Is it some sort of tag?

For #3 ("Get hashes of files in repo..."), my gut feeling is you can skip this completely. Git already has hashes of every object in the repo, and they are guaranteed in every commit, so this would be redundant. It would make more sense to generate hashes for files outside of the repo, such as generated binaries and artifacts which would be part of deployed content. Even then, it would be abnormal to store the hashes of those artifacts back into the code repo. Instead those would normally be stored in the artifacts repo for validation purposes.

(The combination of my comments might be turning into an answer...) If you take out step 3 (either skip it or move it to the artifacts repo), then since tags can be pushed after the fact, then that leaves steps 1 and 2. If you can amend these into a single commit from one pipeline before the first push, you should be able to avoid force pushing a shared branch.
